# Changing GPIO pin configuration on the fly

Tags: gpio, pins, stm32f0, cortex-m0

I am using STM32F0 based ARM Cortex-M0 micro controller in my project. Because of lack of available pins, I need to use one pin as an ADC-input and as a GPIO-digital-out (not at the same time, but in the same application i.e. changing on the fly).

My question: Is it possible to change such configuration during run-time? Let's assume that I am operating my MUX in the right way (High-Z when needed).

Thanks

Comment: Yes\$\$\$\$\$\$

Comment: Is there any particular reason you think that this would be a problem?

Comment: So I need to configure both the GPIO and the ADC?
By ADC I mean to enable/disable the appropriate channel

Comment: This mostly seems to be a problem of the code generator you are using. Such I/O multiplexing usually has to be done by hand-written code. Maybe you have to refrain from using the usual libraries, or at least the most simple examples on how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing an analog function of a pin with a digital function is a bad thing to do.  It is bad enough that a pin of one type is next to another one. Experienced engineers spend a lot of effort on design and layout to get digital coupling and noise away from analog signals.

I suggest that you work to find two digital functions that you can time share on a pin.